# Does the target database need to have the same structure of the source database before to use IMPDP?

Tags: oracle, backup, impdp, datapump, expdp

When I do a import from another database have I need the same estruture of the source database in the target database?

For example, if my source database use ASM and my target database no, what have I to do before to make the import?

In the last time I received an error during the import. The error was about the creation of a tablespace and the datafiles. The erro said that the path of the datafile does not exist. For this problem I used the remap_datafile. But I wonder if is there another way to do it without this parameters. Mainly if there are several datafiles

In the last time I didn't use ASM, it was file system on different machines

My scenery is a full export and import

Comment: What happened when you try?

Comment: In the last time I received an error during the import. The error was about the creation of a tablespace and the datafiles. The erro said that the path of the datafile does not exist. For this problem I used the remap_datafile. But I wonder if is there another way to do it without this parameters. Mainly if there are several datafiles.

Comment: But in the last time I don't used ASM, it was file system of different machines. It was just a example.

Comment: There are several types of exports and imports used for different purposes (i.e. are we talking about a full database export?   A table-level export?  Something else?) so it is helpful to provide a bit more context.  If you're trying to do an ad hoc copy of a table from one instance to another, I'd generally find it easier to pre-create the table on the destination database (making whatever DDL changes are appropriate to map to a different physical structure, character set, etc) and just import the data.  But that answer likely changes if you're trying to pull in thousands of tables.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, but my scenery is a full export and  import

Answer (score 2):

The new database can have a different directory structure and even storage system, but you'd need some preparation before running the import. Especially, you'd need to create the tablespaces in advance with the correct (new) storage parameters (and of course the required size). Then `impdp` would not have to create them (an error might still be shown, but import should proceed).

Make sure to give the tablespaces the same names (or use the corresponding `REMAP` parameters on import). No need to apply quotas etc, that the import should take care of then (when creating the users).